# How to write a windows batch file that checks the timestamp of a file, that can be ran as a prebuild event in visual studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, file, batch-file, cmd

We have a project with a generated version number based on the todays date.
Therefore we want to conditionally rebuild it, if the file was last built yesterday.

I'm aware of the following method:

`for %a in (C:/myFile.txt) do set FileDate=%~ta`

This outputs as expected:

`set FileDate=06.11.2019 14:04`

Writing a batchfile (batchfile.bat) for it produces similar results:

```
@echo off
set %outputFile%=%1%
echo %outputFile%
for %%a in (%outputFile%) do set FileDate=%%~ta
echo %FileDate%
```

```
C:/myFile.txt
FileDate=06.11.2019 14:04
```

However I run into problems, when try calling this batchfile, as a visual studio .csproj prebuild event:

```
call "C:/path/to/batchFile.bat" "C:/myFile.txt"
```

This outputs the following:

```
C:/myFile.txt
ECHO is on.
```

So the value isn't stored properly into FileDate. Any pointers on where I am going wrong? I'm unable to find any information on it online

Comment: Provide more code, including the command you run to execute it.

Comment: Good question. I ran it as a prebuild-event in a visual studio c# project. 
Running it through the command prompt worked fine.

Comment: Okay. Then I don't really understand your question. You might need to rewrite it entirely.

Comment: Seems like I have to go over everything again. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Line two is just plain wrong, because there's no defined variable named `outputFile`, _(```set =...```)_. Windows uses backward slashes as its directory separators, and always has done. Please change, `C:/myFile.txt`, and `C:/path/to/batchFile.bat` to `C:\myFile.txt`, and `C:\path\to\batchFile.bat` respectively. Also `%1%` is wrong, it should be `%1` and preferably `%~1`. Also you should define variables using this syntax, ```set "varname=stringvalue"```. You should therefore change `set %outputFile%=%1%` to `set "outputFile=%~1"` and `set FileDate=%%~ta` to `set "FileDate=%%~ta"`.

Comment: You should also change ```(%outputFile%)``` to ```("%outputFile%")```, to ensure that filenames with spaces or poison characters work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This works correctly for me:

```
@echo off
set outputFile=%1
echo %outputFile%
for %%a in (%outputFile%) do set FileDate=%%~ta
echo %FileDate%
```

I named the file `test.bat`, and I execute it against itself in the same directory with this:

```
test test.bat
```

The output is this:

```
test.bat
03/23/2023 10:14 AM
```

Answer (score -2):

My problem was that I tried creating this variable in an IF-scope

such as:

```
IF [%buildcounter%]==[] (
for %%a in (%outputFile%) do set FileDate=%%~ta
)
```

Appearently variables cannot be created within an IF-statement.

Comment: This is aside from the main issues with what you posted! In fact it isn't even part of your question code. Additionally variables can be created within an `If` statement. You just haven't done it properly. Try reading up on delayed variable expansion.